# Python Regex boolean 'or' doesn't select all matches

Tags: python, regex, boolean-logic

I'm trying to match a number of sub-strings within a string.

The areas of interest are in the format of:

```
Sample1: "text text text[One]"
Sample2:"text text text[One/Two]"
Sample3:"text text text[One/Two/Three]"
```

I'm trying to get a list of the numbers using regex in the following way:

```
numbers = re.findall('(\[|\/)(\w+)(\/|\])', str)
```

However, group2 produces:

```
#Sample1
['One']
#Sample2
['One']
#Sample3
['One','Three']
```

No matter what, I can't get it to match the second number between a '/' and either a ']' or a '/'. However, I don't understand why it isn't matching '/Two/' as the '/' character is an option in both alternatives.

I've also tried framing it in a different way with the following regex:

```
re.findall('[\[]?[\/]?(\w+)[\/]?[\]]?', str)
```

and although it gives me the desired results, it also gives me all the words in the preceding text as well.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: If a slash gets matched as group 3 for one word, *it is no longer available* to match group 1 for the next word.  One possible solution would be to make group 3 a positive lookahead, so that it doesn't actually consume the text it matched.

Comment: `re.split("[][]", mystring)[1].split('/')` perhaps... Also, using `str` as a variable name is not advisable.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for that clarification, that makes perfect sense. I can't believe I've been using regex for this long and didn't realise that the letters get 'consumed' after each match!

Comment: @twalberg Yes that worked well too - don't worry str isn't my actual variable, I just put that for clarification as my actual variable was just a random letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookbehind and lookahead so the `[`, `/` and `]` are not part of the match:

```
>>> [re.findall('(?<=\[|\/)\w+(?=\/|\])', s) for s in samples]
[['One'], ['One', 'Two'], ['One', 'Two', 'Three']]
```

This way, the intermediate `/` can be used for two matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = ["text text text[One]", "text text text[One/Two]",  "text text text[One/Two/Three]"]
import re
final_data = [[b.split('/') for b in re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', i)][0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[['One'], ['One', 'Two'], ['One', 'Two', 'Three']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex too:

```
import re
regex = r"\[.+?\]"
Sample1= "text text text[One]"
Sample2= "text text text[One/Two]"
Sample3= "text text text[One/Two/Three]"
lines=[Sample1,Sample2,Sample3]
subres = [re.findall(r"\[(.+[^\/])\]", s) for s in lines]
result = [res[0].split('/') for res in subres]

print(result)
```

result:

[['One'], ['One', 'Two'], ['One', 'Two', 'Three']]

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your target strings are always going to be in the format you've shown, then why not just find all the *numbers separated by slashes* first, and then split the result on `/`?

```
Sample3 = "text text text[One/Two/Three]"
re.findall('\[(.*)\]', Sample3)[0].split('/')
```

Output:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```